# Number Validation Not Working

Tags: javascript, html, validation, input, operators

I have an input field thats only supposed to take numbers inbetween 1 and 4. If the number is inbetween 1 and 4, it runs some code. If not, it shoots an alert that tells the user to try again with a number between 1 and 4. Here is my code

```
var number = document.getElementById("num").value;
     if(Number(number) === 1 || Number(number) === 2 || Number(number) === 3 || Number(number) === 4 ){
               //success code here///
             }
     else if(Number(number) !== 1 || Number(number) !== 2 || Number(number) !== 3 || Number(number) !== 4) { 
        }       alert("Please type a whole number between(and including) 1 and 4 into the input field.");
```

I learned that the '.value;' function returns a string, even if the value is a number. So I put the var 'number' in the Number(); function that converts it to a number.
   The problem is, when I type 1 into the input field. It shoots the alert even though it equals 1. None of the other numbers work either. I checked the console, and there are no syntax errors(also according to DreamWeaver). Help would be highly appreciated :)

Comment: You don't need the second `if` test. If it's not one of the numbers you've tested, then you already know what you need to know.

Comment: What @Pointy said change `else if(){` into `else{`

Comment: @Pointy it still isn't working, its shooting the alert

Comment: I think you just had a mistake your `alert("Please...");` is outside of the last `}` meaning it'll run every time.

Comment: It helps to run your code through http://jsbeautifier.org - that would make the typo much more obvious.

Comment: Your alert is outside of the braces and there could be a problem with your HTML. Run an alert on number after you get the value and put an alert in the success to make sure it's firing. http://jsfiddle.net/http://jsfiddle.net/56h03cnh/

Comment: @caleb.breckon, thats a broken link. Also, I basically redid all of the alerts to check if they were outside its if statement. http://jsfiddle.net/alienc/f6oq1sf1/9/   That is a jsfiddle of the thing and If you check that box and type a string or ANY number into the input field, it goes through.

Answer (score 1):

I think you made a simple mistake of putting your alert outside the `else if` clause.

However there are a few other things you can do to make that a little more readable and efficient.

```
// Call Number() here so you only have to do it once
var number = Number(document.getElementById("num").value);
// You can also do something like parseInt(document.getElementById("num").value)

// Now check to see if Number() or parseInt() actually parsed an integer out of their input
// and then check that if it's outside your number range
if (isNaN(number) || number < 1 || number > 4) {
    alert("Please type a whole number between(and including) 1 and 4 into the input field.");
} else {
    // Do Successful code
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/alienc/f6oq1sf1/9/ [in the 'gen()' function] I redid all statements, still not working. Its accepting strings and any number even though I followed your code.(Check 'basic hiragana' and then type a string or any number in the number field, then press 'gen romaji', some values through even though the code explicitly says not to)

Comment: I see two little problems.  First you never gave the variable `number` a value.  I think right after the `allhiragana.checked` line, you'll want to do something like `var number = Number(numInput.value);`.  Then you have one other little bug, you are checking for numbers less than 1 and greater than 4, instead of between the two.  So you can change that check to be ` else if (number >= 1 && number <= 4) {` or you can switch the code in the `else if` and the `else`

Comment: I did define number. I just realized there is no reason for 'numInput.value' because thats what the 'number' value is; the val of the input-field. Also, when I type a string into the box, it's displaying the alert for 'type a number between 1 and 4'. This is wrong, as I put 'if(isNaN(number) == true) { alert("Oops!Please type a whole number into the input field.");' and this means that if that alert isn't shooting, than it's somehow passing this conditional?

Comment: You defined `number`, but you defined it when the page loaded, so it will always be an empty string, it won't update it's value as the input box gets updated.  You have to set the value of `number` inside `gen()` otherwise it'll have the wrong value.  Let's work through the other problem once you get that resolved.

Comment: Wow. All I had to do was move where I defined number. Now everything is resolved. Thanks!

Comment: The important thing to remember here is that setting a value on a javascript variable isn't binding to an input field, you're just grabbing the value at a specific point in time.

Answer (score 0):

we can write like this also

```
var patt1 = /[1-4]/g;
if(patt1.test(number)){
     //success code here///
}
else{
    alert("Please type a whole number between(and including) 1 and 4 into the input field.");
}
```

Comment: Using Regular Expressions like that should work, but you really should use Regular Expressions as a last resort (or to greatly simplify the code).  Something like this is lightweight enough that it won't matter, but I figured it was worth mentioning.